# Why does Advanced FilterCopy only return the first row when given a criteria in the criteria range?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I'm doing a project where I use VBA Advanced Filter to copy and filter the data depending on account numbers through the criteria range.

When copying with no criterias, it seems to execute flawlessly, but as soon as I input a criteria (an accountnumber), it only returns the first row of the data, no matter which accountnumber is used. I have tried with different kinds of criteria operators ( i.e. ="=510045" or <510045) but to no avail. Following is the VBA code for the Advanced Filter:

```
Sub AdvFilter_country()
 'error statement
  On Error GoTo errHandler:
 'run the advanced filter
    Sheets("Landrap").Range("A6:H300").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Landrap").Range("A1:H2"),CopyToRange:=Sheets("Landrap").Range("Q6:X300"), Unique:=False
 'error block
  On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
  errHandler::
  MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & "The error number is:  " _
  & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
  "Please notify the administrator"

End Sub
```

The criteria range consists of 2 rows where the first row contains the same headers as the data and the second row is for criterias.

Info about the data:

- All the data are numbers, but is registered as strings
- All the data start with 510* and then a unique number afterwards
- The data has 4 spaces in front i.e. "    510045"

**Anyone know why it ignores my criterias and just gives the first row in the range?**

---

Website I used to get an idea of criteria operators: http://www.excelfunctions.net/ExcelAdvancedFilter.html

Comment: I'm guessing your List Range and Copy To Range do not include the column headers. If your column headers are in row 5, make you List Range A5:A300 and your Copy To Range Q5:X300.

Comment: Thanks Dave and pnuts for replying so fast! Dave's suggestion solved it. I had defined a header for it, but apparently by not including it in the copy range, it had no idea how filter it. Thanks again!

Comment: If you solved your problem, answer your own question. Please DO NOT edit the answer into your question like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: As Dave replied in the comments, in my copy range, I hadn't included the header which was in A5:H5. So the ranges are A5:H300 and Q5:X300 instead.

Comment: I removed the answer from the question and posted it here as a community wiki on behalf of the OP.

Comment: Thanks for changing it. I will do this futurewise.